# How to define morphisms and arrows to construct an equalizer diagram.

Tags: category-theory

How would I define the parallel pair of morphisms and monomorphism from $Nat(F,G)$ to $\prod_{j\in ObJ}\textbf{C}(Fj,Gj)$ in this problem?

Show that for any small category J, any locally small category $\textbf{C}$, and any parallel pair of functors $F,G:J\to \textbf{C}$, there is an equalizer diagram

$$Nat(F,G)\rightarrowtail\prod_{j\in ObJ}\textbf{C}(Fj,Gj)\rightrightarrows \prod_{f:j\to j'\in mor J}\textbf{C}(Fj,Gj').$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let rewrite the indicies in the diagram you gave :
$$
\prod_{k \in Ob(J)}\mathbf{C}(Fk,Gk)\rightrightarrows\prod_{f:i\to j}\mathbf{C}(Fi,Gj).
$$

By universal property, a map into a product is fully described by the maps to it's components.

Let $f:i\to j$ a morphism in $\mathbf C$.

The $f$-component of the first map is given by the composition :
$$
\prod_{k} \mathbf{C}(Fk,Gk) \to \mathbf{C}(Fi,Gi)\to \mathbf{C}(Fi,Gj)
$$
where the first is the $i$ projection, and the second is composing with $G(f)$, namely the map $G(f)_*$.

The $f$-component of the second map is given by the composition :
$$
\prod_{k} \mathbf{C}(Fk,Gk) \to \mathbf{C}(Fj,Gj)\to \mathbf{C}(Fi,Gj)
$$
where the first is the $j$ projection, and the second is precomposing with $F(f)$, namely the map $F(f)^*$.

So we get the two desired maps of the diagram. Then an element that equalizes those two maps should be an element $(\alpha_k)_{k \in Ob(J)}$ of $\prod_{k} \mathbf{C}(Fk,Gk)$ such that for any $f : i \to j$, $F(f)^* (\alpha_j) = G(f)_* (\alpha_i)$, i.e.
$$
\alpha_j \circ F(f) = G(f) \circ \alpha_i
$$
which is the equation defining natural transformations.
So, by definition, the equalizer of those two maps is $Nat(F,G)$.

Comment: Then how do we define the other components? You only defined the $f-component$

Comment: I described the $f$-component for any $f$ morphism in $\mathbf{C}$

Comment: How do we check the universal property?

Comment: $\prod_{f:i\to j} \mathbf{C}(Fi,Gj)$ has the universal property of the product since it is a product.

Comment: I mean the universal property of the equalizer?

Comment: In the category of sets, the equaliser of two parallel maps is the subset of elements of the domain that are sent to the same image by the two parallel maps. I described explicitly what such an element is : a natural transformation.