# Proving that something is the set of natural transformations between two functors.

Tags: category-theory

Let $F, G:\mathcal{C}\rightrightarrows\mathcal{E}$ with $\mathcal{C}$ small and $\mathcal{E}$ locally small. Prove that the end over $\mathcal{C}$ of the bifunctor $\mathcal{E}(F-,G-):\mathcal{C}^{op}\times\mathcal{C}\to Set$ is the set of natural transformations from $F$ to $G$.

How would I proceed about proving this?

Comment: What've you tried?

Comment: Hi, please look at [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3361762/how-to-define-morphisms-and-arrows-to-construct-an-equalizer-diagram/3363444#3363444], in the awnser, I detail what the set of natural transformations should be and it is the end of $\mathcal{E}(F(-),G(-))$ by definition of ends.